# error: hp-systray cannot be run as root. Exiting

Tags: ubuntu

I am installing HP printer drivers and HP device manager utility in my ubuntu 11.04 machine with `root user permissions`.But even after installation systray does not work.It exits with error

```
error: hp-systray cannot be run as root. Exiting.
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some things to consider.

Stock Ubuntu does not provide a gui or X environment for the root account. So, unless you have done a lot of extra work there might be no systray at all for your utility to work with.

Generally, there's no need for printer utilities to have root access. Why do you need it?

If there are special needs, you might want to set up a print server on another machine or in a VM where your normal users have no access to anything except the print queues.